# Rails Wicked PDF error log (image not rendering)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I am using Rails 5 and Wicked PDF to render a PDF. On my localhost everything works fine but on my Heroku production server the image is not being rendered. First guess of course is that the image is only available on localhost but that's not the case.

If I render the same view as HTML the image is available but as PDF the image does not show.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag 'logo-invoice.jpg', class: 'logo' %>
```

It shows only a small grey square. The Rails log does not show any errors. I event tried the full URL without using Rails tags:

```
<img src="https://example.com/assets/logo-invoice-759b0991be66c5119a10b30680ad8902eaceacc33cfcc04afbc839d3ec404870.jpg">
```

Still no success. Problem is I don't know where to start debugging this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wicked PDF can have issues rendering images from the asset pipeline. Try using the `wicked_pdf_asset_base64` helper method i.e.

```
<%= image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('logo-invoice.jpg'), class: 'logo' %>
```